# Will Java catch an Exception multiple times if it inherits another Exception?

Tags: java, inheritance, exception

given these classes:

```
public static class SuperException extends Exception {
}


public static class MyException extends SuperException {
}
```

and this happening at runtime:

```
try{
   throw new MyException();
} catch (MyException e) {
   catcher1();
} catch (SuperException e) {
   catcher2();
}
```

which methods will be invoked?  just the first? both? does it make any difference in which order I write the catch blocks?

Comment: Any proper IDE will warn you that the second catch is unreachable.

Comment: The first catch of course, because the runtime type is `MyException`, the other one is unnecessary

Comment: It always catch the first and most specific which is why you can't write the exceptions in the opposite order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the first (`catcher1`). The **first** matching `catch` block is executed, and none others.

With the code in the question, the second `catch` block is unreachable and won't compile. But if your `try` block contained code that may throw `MyException`, and also code that may throw a `SuperException` that isn't a `MyException`, and if you want to handle `MyException` differently from `SuperException`, you could have both of those blocks (and you would want them in that order).